# Analyticity of the Cauchy Function

Tags: complex-analysis

I a trying to solve exercises on Mathematical Analysis I by Zorich and I am stuck on a problem about analytic functions:

a) Investigate whether the Cauchy function $f(z) = e ^ {- \frac{1}{z  ^2}}$ when $z \not = 0$ and $0$ when $z = 0$ is continuous at $z = 0$.

b) Is the restriction $f|_\mathbb{R}$ of the function $f$ in a) to the real line continuous?

c) Does the Taylor series of the function $f$ in $a)$ exist at the point $z_0 =0 ?$

d) Are there functions analytic at a point $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ whose Taylor series converge only at the point $z_0$?

e) Invent a power series $\sum_{n = 0} ^ \infty c_n (z - z_0) ^ n$ that converges only at the point $z_0$.

So I have solved parts a) and b) but I am stuck on c). My guess is that the Taylor series does not exist as the function is not even continuous, let alone differentiable, but the problem is framed in such a way that I believe  the Cauchy function should provide an answer to c) and d). Can somebody help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard example of a $C^\infty$ function on $\mathbb R$ whose Taylor series does not converge to the function. You are correct: the Taylor series of $f$ about $0$ does not exist (because, as you note, $f$ is not continuous), but the Taylor series of $\left. f\right|_\mathbb R$ does exist and is $0$.  But part (c) as you wrote it doesn't ask about $\left. f\right|_\mathbb R$ .

For (d), the answer is no: depending on how you define "analytic", this is either direct from the definition or from an important theorem: see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions).

For (e), try a series where $a_n$ grows so quickly that the radius of convergence is $0$.

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful. I have solved the problem using your hints.